# Delete Table row using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML table with insert and delete row functionality and its working perfectly. But delete functionality works with checkbox + delete button.

When i want to delete a row, first i checked the checkbox and then press delete button. I want to make it directly with delete button. Below is my code,

```
function deleteRow(tableID)
{
try
     {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++)
            {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked)
                {
                if (rowCount <= 1)
                    {
                    alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                    break;
                    }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
                }
            }
        } catch(e)
            {
            alert(e);
    }
   getValues();
}

<a onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')">Delete Row</a>

<table id="dataTable">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Name"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note : Atleast 1 row should be there (Cannot delete all the rows)

Comment: where exactly is the delete button? do you have one below the table and you want to delete the focused row? or one delete button besides each row?

Comment: @melc ohhh sorry i forget to add delete button, I updated my question, now check it

Comment: If you use only the delete button how do you plan to identify which row(s) should be deleted?

Comment: @DavidThomas yes I used delete button directly with each row but it delete all rows. I think if we use 1 specific ID with that button but i don't have any idea how to do it

Comment: Why are you complicating this? Stick with the checkbox, it's a user-interface people are familiar with, and far less complex than trying to guess which row should be acted on. And using an `id` would identify a particular row, yes. But what should happen on the second click, or the third?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use one button, a usable solution is to select/unselect the rows to be deleted onclick. This way multi select and delete is also supported. For example,

http://jsfiddle.net/Nt4wZ/

**js**

```
function selectRow(row) {
    if (row.className.indexOf("selected") != -1) {
        row.className = row.className.replace("selected", "");
    } else {
        row.className += " selected";
    }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
    try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            /*var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];*/
            /*if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked)*/

            if (row.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].className.indexOf("selected")!=-1) {
                if (rowCount <= 1) {
                    alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                    break;
                }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
    //getValues();
}
```

**html**

```
<a onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')">Delete Row</a>

<table id="dataTable">
    <tr>
        <!-- <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td> -->
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Name" onclick="selectRow(this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!-- <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td> -->
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Name" onclick="selectRow(this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**css**

```
input.selected {
    border-color:lightgreen;
}
```

**EDIT** *- response to comments*

If you want to have a delete button for each row and use that instead, you can do something like the following,

http://jsfiddle.net/GRgMb/

**html**

```
<table id="dataTable">
    <tr>
        <!-- <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td> -->
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Name" /><input type="button" value="delete" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable',this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!-- <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td> -->
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Name" /><input type="button" value="delete" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable',this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**js**

```
function deleteRow(tableID,currentRow) {
    try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            /*var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];*/
            /*if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked)*/

            if (row==currentRow.parentNode.parentNode) {
                if (rowCount <= 1) {
                    alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                    break;
                }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
    //getValues();
}
```

Comment: thanks you so much. Its good but isn't it possible to delete the row with having their own delete button

Comment: @sHAmsuLaRiFeEn you are welcome! I updated the answer with a second example.

Comment: your are great :) now this is what i was looking for. thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

This code is an example:

```
    $(document).on('click', 'img.imgdel', function deleteRow() {
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      return false;
   });
```

https://codepen.io/dionejpmc/pen/vYxLdyX

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: This is jQuery, not JavaScript. The question does not specify jQuery and in 2021 I wouldn't recommend jQuery.  In addition, closeest() and remove() are now native JavaScript functions, so this could easily have been written as pure JavaScript